# <TextView /> OR <TextView></TextView>

Tags: android, xml

in android xml file, i often see two different format:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/DrawableResources" />
```

OR

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/DrawableResources" ></TextView>
```

Are they the same? Are all the XML tag in android without contents between `<TextView>` and `</TextView>` can be written in the two format ?

Comment: There is no difference, just one is shorthand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a shortcut which I prefer using. However, some tags do use the long method such as *LinearLayout* and *RelativeLayout* and *ScrollView* to name a few as these examples accept content within themselves.

Have a read of the docs here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same!!

`<TextView/>` is shorthand of `<TextView></TextView>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a syntax shortcut available in all XML documents, for tags with no body. I prefer the former, but you can write either one.

Answer (score 0):

yes,  is shorthand of `<tag></tag>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the same. In the same way as you see it in HTML and ASP tags like

```
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Example" />
```

when no child elements present

Answer (score 0):

Yes This can be written in both the ways, Both are same.

Generaly the following way is used in case of if the view is a parent view and need to contain some other views in it, such views are called view groups like Linear layouts, RealtiveLayout, scrollView etc.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/DrawableResources" >

<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/DrawableResources" />

</LinearLayout>
```